# How different task may affect processor temperature

Tags: processor, temperature

I am doing an application that warm up the processor as much as possible to test the cooling subsystem. The first naive attempt was just to created as many threads as the processor cores and run an infinite loop in each thread. It actually increase the temperature but I want to do something more.

I think that different instructions have different temperature footprint. Particularly I am interested in Intel Xeon E5-2620 v3.

So my question is: how to write code (preferably in C/Linux) that warm up the processor more than simple infinite loop?

Comment: Have you tried with some arithmetic operation, like cryptographic primitives? I once was infected with a Bitcoin miner and noticed it because my fan was always at full speed. Integer and FP operations should warm the CPU up. I'm not sure about it, but I would avoid accessing memory operands, unless you are confident that they are always cached. Also avoid long chains of data dependencies.

Comment: I guess that for example MMX or SSE instructions may consume more power than simple FP calculation but I hoped that somebody already know some numbers and I avoid reinventing a wheel. The instruction and data cache is other story. I have heard two different opinions - 1. avoid cache misses because CPU is waiting for memory and it is idle then. 2. Do a lot of cache misses because the operation "store to cache" consumes more power than simple move to register. Well both arguments sounds reasonable. I am planning to do a measurement but I hoped that I could save effort...

Comment: By FP I mean Floating Point calculations, they can be done with the old x87 or with modern SSE/AVX. I found that people, like overclockers, use a program called [Prime95](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime95#Use_for_stress_testing) for stressing the CPU.